# Save if Modified, C#, WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, savefiledialog, savechanges

Trying to make an Winforms Application, with New, Open, Close, Save, SaveAs functions.
When I am editing a particular file/form on opening it, and then if I click 'New' or 'Open' or 'Close' or 'Exit' accidently, without saving it,'SaveIfModified' does not works.
It directly closes without any warning which i mentioned in "DialogResult".

Below is my code.

```
    private bool SaveIfModified()
    {

        if (!Modified)
            return true;

        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("The current file has been Updated. Do you want to Save Changes?", "Do you want to Save Changes", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (FileName != null)
            {
                return WriteFile(FileName);
            }
            else
            {
                SaveFileDialog.FileName = FileName;
                if (SaveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
                    return WriteFile(SaveFileDialog.FileName);
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else // DialogResult.Cancel
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the VS debugger tell you?

Comment: So it doesnt show you the MessageBox? In that case you are not calling this method when the window is being closed.

Comment: @CathalMF: the method could be called - another reason for not getting the MessageBox would be that Modified is false.

Comment: private void MenuItemButtonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (SaveIfModified())
                ClearFile();
        }

Comment: I am calling the method..

Comment: Attach the debugger and see what the value of Modified is inside your method.

Comment: Only two possible conditions exist that would cause the dialog not to display. Either you aren't calling this function at all or else `Modified` is equal to `false`. Set a breakpoint on the `if` statement.

Comment: It is a basic design problem.  A bool can only return two values, but your dialog (correctly) distinguishes between three conditions.  So the caller can't tell the difference between "don't do anything" and "fine, no need to save".  So doesn't know that the window should not be closed.

Comment: So where is the mistake in my code! Can you elaborate @HansPassant

Comment: @HansPassant, this is off topic, but just wanted to say it's good to see nobugz still helping out!